# Power BI summing for one value, not summing for other

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I have a formula in my DAX

Difference in Open WBS since last Qend =

VAR PreviousPeriodSum =
CALCULATE(
SUM('RA_Run_Time_Automatic_History'[Open WBS]),
'RA_Run_Time_Automatic_History'[Period Int] = 7
)
RETURN
PreviousPeriodSum

When i put a veriable insead of 7, it didnt work. Then i tried directly writing 6. But 6 is not working. I have values against column Period int as 6,7,8. 8 and 7 is working, but 6 is not. When i get regular totals i can see totals of Period Int=6, but when i put it to this formula i cannot see it.

As above
)
RETURN
PreviousPeriodSum

When i put a veriable insead of 7, it didnt work. Then i tried directly writing 6. But 6 is not working. I have values against column Period int as 6,7,8. 8 and 7 is working, but 6 is not. When i get regular totals i can see totals of Period Int=6, but when i put it to this formula i cannot see it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use

```
 CALCULATE(
SUM('RA_Run_Time_Automatic_History'[Open WBS]),
'RA_Run_Time_Automatic_History'[Period Int] = CurrentPeriod - 1
    )
```

Or does previous mean something else to you?